# Play real time audio with swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, real-time, core-audio

We have a bluetooth device that streams artificial audio data to an iOS app.
I say artificial because this 'sound' is not recorded, but synthesized by ways of transfer functions applied on another signal. The generated audio data has a frequency range of 30 - 80 Hz.

The data is sampled at 500Hz, and in Int32 type, with values 0 -> 4096 (12 bit).

Question: Using the core Audio framework, what steps should I take to playback this data through the iOS device's speakers as it is streaming in (i.e real-time playback)?

Comment: Are you sure it's at 500Hz? That's only signal content up to 250Hz, which isn't much from an audio perspective, certainly not enough for anything except (again, assuming this is destined for human hearing) very low bass and low percussive sounds.

Comment: Yes Linuxios, we are dealing with heart sounds, which have a frequency range of ~20 - ~80 Hz, and are pretty much low percussive sounds!

Comment: OK, just wanted to confirm, since for most applications that number would have been a typo :).

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out I edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Core Audio (Audio Units, Audio Queue API) would be appropriate for near-real-time streaming playback (very short buffers).  You will likely need to upsample your data to something more like 44.1 or 48 kHz, which are the typical iOS device hardware audio output rates.